# Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: angular, firebase

Im trying to show up a list of cars on my html component but it throws me that error...  I'm using Firebase

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, 
AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

import { Cars } from '../models/cars';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { ToastrService } from './toastr.service';
import { User } from '../../shared/models/user';

@Injectable()
export class BusesService {

userDetail: User;

buses: AngularFirestoreCollection<Cars>;
buse : AngularFirestoreDocument<Cars>;

constructor(
  private db: AngularFirestore,
  private authService: AuthService,
  private toastrService: ToastrService
  ) {
 }
 getBuses(){ 
   this.userDetail = this.authService.getLoggedInUser();

   this.buses = this.db.collection('cars',
   ref => ref.where('userId', '==', this.userDetail.$key));

   return this.buses;
  }
 }
```

**Component where i use the service**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Cars } from '../../../shared/models/cars';
import { AuthService } from '../../../shared/services/auth.service';
import { BusesService } from '../../../shared/services/buses.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'src/app/shared/services/toastr.service';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-lista-camiones',
 templateUrl: './lista-camiones.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./lista-camiones.component.scss']
 })

export class ListaCamionesComponent implements OnInit {

 productList: Cars[];
 productObject: Cars;

 loading = false;

constructor(
  public authService : AuthService,
  private busesService : BusesService,
  private toastrService : ToastrService
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.getAllProducts();
}

  getAllProducts(){
    console.log("getting Cars");

   this.loading = true;
    const x = this.busesService.getBuses();
    x.snapshotChanges().subscribe(
      (product) => {
        this.loading = false;

        this.productList = [];
        console.log(" products" + product);

        product.forEach((element) => {

          this.productObject = element.payload.doc.data();
          this.productObject.userid = element.payload.doc.id;
          console.log("data : " + this.productObject.userid);
          this.productList.push(this.productObject as Cars);
        });
      },
      (err) => {
        this.toastrService.error('Error while fetching Car List', err);
      }
     );

    }
}
```

**Model**

```
export class Cars {
   userid: string;
   driverid: number;
   unitid: string;
   description: string;
}
```

**Error**

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not a
>   function TypeError: undefined is not a function
>       at Array.map ()
>       at webpackAsyncContext ($_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object:45)

Comment: Does `this.authService.getLoggedInUser()` return an observable?

Comment: the user itself its observable `user: Observable<firebase.User>;`  in the class AuthService, but the metod just return loggedUser

Comment: So are you saying `getLoggedInUser()` returns an observable, or just a user object? Are you sure that you are getting the user? You might try logging `this.userDetail` to make sure you have a user object there

Comment: i solved it, i was putting the class in another place and the service wasnt int the shared.module.ts.... now the routes are good and shows the page but now i have an error on my Query  to get the data xd  `ListaCamionesComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR FirebaseError: Function Query.where() requires a valid third argument, but it was undefined.`

Comment: It is saying `this.userDetail.$key` is undefined